# Limits of positive sequence with $(n+1)x_{n+1}-nx_n<0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let's consider a sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge1}$ of strictly positive numbers, such that $(n+1)x_{n+1}-nx_n<0$. Prove that is convergent and find its limit.

I proved that it is convergent by using $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<\frac{n}{n+1}$, so $x_{n+1}<x_n$ and therefore the series is strictly decreasing. I do not know how to find it limit.

I am grateful for your help!

Comment: The word is "sequence", not "series". A series is an infinite **sum**.

Answer (score 2):

We show by induction that

$$0< x_n<\frac{x_1}{n}$$

for all $n\geq2$. We will use the inequality

$$x_{n+1}<\frac{n}{n+1}x_n,$$

which we get from rearranging the given inequality. For the base case it is clear, as

$$x_2<\frac{x_1}{2}$$

by the inequality. Suppose now that it holds for some $n\geq 2$. Then

$$x_{n+1}<\frac{n}{n+1}x_n<\frac{n}{n+1}\frac{x_1}{n}=\frac{x_{1}}{n+1}.$$

The assertion now follows. Now using the squeeze theorem it follows, as

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_1}{n}=0,$$

that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$$

by the inequality we proved.